# How to know the size of table for a particular day in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to know the size of data in a table for a particular day? Is it possible in SQL server.

I have below query `sp_spaceused 'FederationAuditLogs'`, but it gives me entire table size for the whole duration. but I want to know let's say just for today.

Please guide me.

Comment: Create a maintenance job that inserts the total value you get each day, then you can run a query comparring days and get the size increased/decreased for the day

Comment: @Brad: Suppose that table has a column as `TimeOfOccurence`. Can I leverage that column to get the size? Can we write a query based on this column value set to a day.

Comment: Data in a table isn't stored with metadata like "this was written today, that was deleted today, this was changed today, etc". If you need to track such changes you need to implement methods to track them; such as what @Brad suggested. Still, you won't be able to tell what changed the values unless you use history table of some kind (and that won't tell you the size changes). It would be impossible to find out that Column `CustomerName` had 17 changes today, increasing the database size by 127kb.

Answer (score 0):

My only idea would be to create a query that returns all rows for that day and then using any language get a sum of all of the values returned sizes.